# replace elements of prediction in custom loss function for tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using a classification model, but would like to write my custom loss function which considers the value as 1 for two of the three categories only if the softmax value is greater than 0.75. The value of the third category is set to 1 if both of the other categories are zero.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred[:,0][y_pred[:,0] > 0.75] = 1
    y_pred[:,0][y_pred[:,0] < 0.75] = 0
    y_pred[:,2][y_pred[:,2] > 0.75] = 1
    y_pred[:,2][y_pred[:,2] < 0.75] = 0
    y_pred[:,1] = 1 - y_pred[:,0] - y_pred[:,2]
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)
```

However I get the error

```
  y_pred[:,0][y_pred[:,0] > 0.75] = 1

TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

is there a way to achieve the same using TensorFlow functions.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

y_pred = y_pred.numpy()

does the trick.